# Angular 4 Uncaught ReferenceError: ng is not defined

Tags: angular

In my superclass I have to inject translateservice because I have to translate some standard message notification/alert.
so I have to add translateservice to all the classes that extends my superclass.

**superclass**

```
constructor(public endPointUrlService: EndpointUrlService, public translate: TranslateService,
    protected route: ActivatedRoute, protected router: Router) {
  }
```

**usercomponent**

```
export class UserListComponent extends Superclass
    constructor(
        private userService: UserService,
        router: Router,
        endPointUrlService: EndpointUrlService,
        route: ActivatedRoute,
        translate: TranslateService) {
    super(endPointUrlService, translate, route, router)
    }
```

Before injecting the translate service I don't have any errors but now:

> ReferenceError: ng is not defined

and

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'geAdapter' of undefined

Comment: have u imported TranslateModule in ur module imports section?

Comment: do you mean in my superclass?

Comment: No, your superclass is not linked to any module. Did you import correctly the `TranslateModule` in every module where your component use the `translateService` with the superclass ?

Comment: yes I have already imported it because all my project use the translations

Comment: please post your understanding if you solved this issue

Comment: @AkshayVijayJain I don't remember how I solve it but ng is not defined is a very unspecific error and it means that there are some error in your code